# Conditional Formatting based on other group of cells

Tags: google-sheets, gs-conditional-formatting

Not sure if this can be done.

Is there a way to use conditional formatting such that if the second column is marked with an `x` as seen in the column below, the sheet will auto append a defined text to the first column?

E.g.

```
Column A | Column B
....@gmail.com  |  x
....@gmail.com  |  
....@gmail.com  |  x
....@gmail.com  |
```

to

```
Column A | Column B
....@gmail.com(some text)  |  x
....@gmail.com  |  
....@gmail.com(some text)  |  x
....@gmail.com  |
```

Comment: I believe you can do it in Excel but not in Google sheets

Answer (score 0):

No.

At present the only Sheets' CF format options are Bold, Italic, Underline, Strikethrough, Font colour, and cell Fill colour.